# Pass dynamic array between view controllers? (programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, cell

I have a new issue is that I have tableview cell and this cell under the didSelect rowAt indexPath function I want to add array and I transfer this array to different view controller cells one by one. I have already did but array didn't pass it seem nil ( [ ] ) when I printed it. I think its very tricky part and solution have to very easy I assume.

Is there any way to pass this array from one controller to new controller ?

Comment: Try delegating. Set the parent as a delegate to the child view controller and using the delegate, get the required data from parent to child.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without protocol because parent to child relationship can't working I think because I can reach child page from everywhere like tab bar button..

Comment: where is the array nil?

Comment: "let detailConVC = pageDetailLauncher()" That's creating a whole new object. So its `secilenUrunlerFromDetay` should be empty or nil, depending on how it is declared.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri array which is take data from other controller's array.

Comment: @Larme is there any way to solve that?

Comment: you should get the actual reference of the controller pageDetailLauncher. What is the relation between the current controller and pageDetailLauncher ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri if I say more clearly first code from pageDetailLauncher which is current controller and I want to pass this array to next viewController which is the part of second code.

Comment: Actually I tried to protocol but its still didn't working..

Comment: Something like `let vc = YourViewController(); vc.dataArray = [1,2,3,4]` should work